# use netty allocator to creat bytebuf per channel or per request?

Tags: java, netty

hi I got a netty server to accept massive tcp connect .

After read the document,

I am not sure about:

1. should I allocate one bytebuf for each channel after initiated?
2. or should I allocate one bytebuf for each request?

In official example it write like this, but I feel strange, if I create bytebuf for each read operation, 
then what is the purpose to do that?

If I allocate a bytebuf for each channel, will it gain more performance advantage?

```
 @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf buff = ctx.alloc().buffer();
        buff.writeBytes(XX);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(buff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will allocate a new buffer whenever you need it as you do not really have a good idea on when you could re-use the buffer by yourself.

That said netty uses the `PooledByteBufAllocator` by default which means buffers are pooled so allocation is not really so expensive here.